# gzcompress() randomly inserting extra data?

Tags: php, http, firefox, compression, zlib

I've been researching this all morning and have decided that as a last-ditch effort, maybe someone on Stack Overflow has a "been-there, done-that" type of answer for me.

#### Background

Recently, I implemented compression on our (intranet-oriented) Apache (2.2) server using filters so that all text-based files are compressed (css, js, txt, html, etc.) via mod_deflate, mentioning nothing about php scripts. After plenty of research on how best to compress PHP output, I decided to use the gzcompress() flavor because the PHP documentation suggests that using zlib library and gzip (using the deflate algorithm, blah blah blah) is preferred over ob_gzipwhatever().

So I copied someone else's method like so:

```
<?php # start each page by enabling output buffering and disabling automatic flushes
ob_start();ob_implicit_flush(0);

(program logic)

print_gzipped_page();

function print_gzipped_page() {
 if (headers_sent())
    $encoding = false;
 elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'x-gzip') !== false )
    $encoding = 'x-gzip';
 elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'gzip') !== false )
    $encoding = 'gzip';
 else
    $encoding = false;

 if($encoding){
    $contents = ob_get_contents(); # get contents of buffer
    ob_end_clean(); # turn off OB and flush buffer
    $size = strlen($contents);
    if ($size < 512) { # too small to be worth a compression
        echo $contents;
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Content-Encoding: $encoding");
        header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
        # 8-byte file header: g-zip file (1f 8b) compression type deflate (08), next 5 bytes are padding
        echo "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"; 
        $contents = gzcompress($contents, 9);
        $contents = substr($contents, 0,$size); # faster than not using a substr, oddly
        echo $contents;
        exit();
    }
} else {
    ob_end_flush();
    exit();
 }
}
```

Pretty standard stuff, right?

#### Problem

Between 10% and 33% of all our PHP page requests sent via Firefox go out fine and come back g-zipped, only Firefox displays the compressed ASCII in lieu of decompressing it. AND, the weirdest part, is that the content size sent back is always 30 or 31 bytes larger than the size of the page correctly rendered. As in, when the script is displayed properly, Firebug shows content size of 1044; when Firefox shows a huge screen of binary gibberish, Firebug shows a content size of 1074.

This happened to some of our users on legacy 32-bit Fedora 12s running Firefox 3.3s... Then it happened to a user with FF5, one with FF6, and some with the new 7.1! I've been meaning to upgrade them all to FF7.1, anyway, so I've been updating them as they have issues, but FF7.1 is still exhibiting the same behavior, just less frequently.

#### Diagnostics

I've been installing Firebug on a variety of computers to watch the headers, and that's where I'm getting confused:
Normal, functioning page response headers:

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2011 18:40:15 GMT
- Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Fedora)
- X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
- Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
- Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
- Pragma: no-cache
- **Content-Encoding: gzip**
- **Vary: Accept-Encoding**
- Content-Length: 1045
- Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=75
- Connection: Keep-Alive
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

(Notice that content-length is generated automatically)

Same page when broken:

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- (everything else identical)
- Content-Length: **1075**

The sent headers always include Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Things I've tried to fix the behavior:

- Explicitly declare content length with uncompressed and compressed lengths
- Not use the substr() of $contents
- Remove checksum at the end of $contents

I don't really want to use gzencode because my testing showed it to be significantly slower (9%) than gzcompress, presumably because it's generating extra checksums and whatnot that I (assumed) the web browsers don't need or use.

I cannot duplicate the behavior on my 64-bit Fedora 14 box running Firefox 7.1. <s>Not once in my testing before rolling the compression code live did this happen to me, neither in Chrome nor Firefox</s>. (Edit: Immediately after posting this, one of the windows I'd left open that sends meta refreshes every 30 seconds finally broke after ~60 refreshes in Firefox) Our handful of Windows XP boxes are behaving the same as the Fedora 12s. Searching through Firefox's Bugzilla kicked up one or two bug requests that were somewhat similar to this situation, but that was for versions pre-dating  3.3 and was with all gzipped content, whereas our Apache gzipped css and js files are being downloaded and displayed without error each time.

The fact that the content-length is coming back 30/31 bytes larger each time leads me to think that something is breaking inside my script/gzcompress() that is mangling something in the response that Firefox chokes on. Naturally, if you play with altering the echo'd gzip header, Firefox throws a "Content Encoding Error," so I'm really leaning towards the problem being internal to gzcompress().

Am I doomed? Do I have to scrap this implementation and use the not-preferred ob_start("ob_gzhandler") method?

I guess my "applies to more than one situation" question would be: Are there known bugs in the zlib compression library in PHP that does something funky when receiving very specific input?

Edit: Nuts. I readgzfile()'d one of the broken, non-compressed pages that Firefox downloaded and, lo and behold!, it echo'd everything back perfectly. =( That means this must be... Nope, I've got nothing.

Comment: Naturally, as soon as I posted that, the Firefox on my machine finally retrieved broken data from the server. ‹xÚµ™moÛ6ÇßûS<´Ù€ÙRšlhI@ to infinity and beyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ding! Ding! Ding! After mulling over this problem all weekend, I finally stumbled across the answer after re-reading the PHP man pages for the umpteenth time... From the zlib PHP documentation, "Whether to **transparently** compress pages." Transparently! As in, nothing else is required to get PHP to compress its output once zlib.output_compression is set to "On". Yeah, embarrassing.

For reasons unknown, the code being called, explicitly, from the PHP script was compressing the already-compressed contents and the browser was simply unwrapping the one layer of compression and displaying the results. Curiously, the strlen() of the content didn't vary when output_compression was on or off, so the transparent compression must occur after the explicit compression, but it occasionally decided not to compress what was already compressed?

Regardless, everything is resolved by simply leaving PHP to its own devices. zlib doesn't need output buffering or anything to compress the output.

Hope this helps others struggling with the wonderful world of HTTP compression.

Answer (score 0):

okay 1st of all you don't seem  to be setting the content length header, which will cause issues, instead, you are making the gzip content longer so that it matches the content length size that you were receiving in the 1st place. This is going to turn ugly. My suggestion is that you replace the lines

```
# 8-byte file header: g-zip file (1f 8b) compression type deflate (08), next 5 bytes are padding
echo "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"; 
$contents = gzcompress($contents, 9);
$contents = substr($contents, 0,$size); # faster than not using a substr, oddly
echo $contents;
```

with

```
$compressed = gzcompress($contents, 9);
$compressed_length = strlen($compressed); /* contains no nulls i believe */
header("Content-length: $compressed_length");
echo "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", $compressed;
```

and see if it helps the situation.

Comment: Well, I've already tried explicitly declaring content-length, and it didn't change anything.

Echoing the gzip header before compressing the contents should be okay, because ob_end_clean() was called which erases the buffer's contents and stops output buffering, so the header won't be encoded with the rest of the contents.

I've re-enabled explicitly declaring the content length, but that didn't fix the problem earlier, so I don't have my hopes very high.

Comment: What do you mean by "instead, you are making the gzip content longer so that it matches the content length size that you were receiving in the 1st place," exactly?

Comment: Yep, that still doesn't prevent the error (if it even is an error) from occurring. It seemed to take a few more refreshes for Firefox to stumble, though.